# When do you use share in httpclient Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it correct way to use share() in request Angular?

```
public find(params: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.PATH}`,
      {
        params: HttpParamsBuilder.buildQueryParams(params),
      }
    ).pipe(share());
  }
```

What is better to use, `switchMap()` or `share()` in this case?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I need to avoid the same requests. Only send requests when parameters are changed

Comment: That seems not the responsibility of find() but for the function that uses it. Besides that switchMap or share will not solve that

Comment: `share()` is a workaround. Observe your codebase probably you call `find()` method several times and after that get rid of the unnecessary invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; Could be OK, depending on your intentions. This, *in combination with additional work in the code calling `find`*, would help you avoid making concurrent calls to an HTTP endpoint with the same parameter.

So its hard to tell if your use of the `share` operator is inappropriate here. It is used to make streams `hot` whilst there is at least one subscriber. Lets say you have a cold observable stream emitting the range 1..5 that has `share` applied such as this:

(This is a marble diagram: ^=Subscribe, !=Unsubscribe, |=Completed)

```
Source         ----1----2----3---   ----1----2----3----4----5----|
Subscriber A   ^---1----2----3--!   
Subscriber B                        ^---1----2----3----4----5----|                          
Subscriber C                                    ^-3----4----5----|
```

Subscriber A subscribes and gets 3 events then unsubscribes. Subscriber B subscribes afterwards and the stream starts afresh. Now when Subscriber C subscribes after the 2nd event, he sees only 3..5 - he missed the first two events because `share` is multicasting and keeping the stream hot whilst there is at least one subscriber.

Your `find` method as written is returning an HTTP stream which will initiate a call to search with the passed parameter when it is subscribed to, and only have one event - either a successful result, or an error.

Assuming a successful result, with multiple subscribers you'll get something like this (where o is the result).

```
Source         ---------o|    ---------o|
Subscriber A   ^--------o|
Subscriber B   ------^--o|
Subscriber C                  ^--------o|
```

Subscriber A makes the first subscription, and whilst the result is pending, Subscriber B also subscribes. They both get notified of the same result. Later, Subscriber C subscribes and a new call is issued and C gets a fresh result.

Whether this is what you want, I can't tell. But to benefit from `share` it would mean you are caching the call to find for a specific parameter somewhere and reusing it. You might be doing this to avoid making concurrent calls for the same parameter at the same time, but not intending to cache the result for future use. You would need some code to manage reusing the observable returned from find.

A caller to `find()` will get a new observable every time; only if there is one caller sharing the returned observable with multiple subscribers will you get the behaviour described above. Call `find()` twice and subscribe to each observable returned, each subscriber will always trigger a separate http call.

If your intention is to actually cache results, you will want to look elsewhere at things like memoizers - examples of memoizing observables can be easily googled.